# apology sentence + but +sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning

I came across with this sentence:

> I’m awfully sorry **but** I haven’t done my homework/ assignment.

what's the role of "but" in the sentence..it sounds like non-apology phrase!

shouldn't it be something like this?

> I’m awfully sorry...I haven’t done my homework/ assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/but):

> **but** (*conjunction*): used to introduce an added statement, usually something that is different from what you have said before.
>   
> ...
> *I'm sorry, but I think you're wrong when you say she did it deliberately.*
> ...

The example given is quite similar to yours, and both phrases are and sound perfectly normal. *I'm awfully sorry, but I haven't done my homework/assignment.* sounds like the person is apologizing to whoever asked him/her about it, and letting him/her know that the homework/assignment was not done.

One workaround for your phrase could be *I'm awfully sorry **for** not having done my homework/assignment.*, but be careful if you do choose to use this alternate phrase, because the context is different:

> I'm awfully sorry, **but** I haven't done my homework/assignment.
> *The person who asked about the homework does not know it hasn't been done, it's unknown.*
> I'm awfully sorry **for** not having done my homework/assignment.
> *Either the person who asked about the homework knows it hasn't been done, and is scolding (for example) him/her, or it has been stated before.*

Answer (score 2):

The implied "contrast" in OP's example isn't with the 3-word apologetic introductory phrase - it's with the entire real-world context as relevant to the circumstances...

> *[I should have done my homework / You expected me to have done it,] **but I haven't***.

Exactly the same "unspecified contrasting referent" would apply with, for example,...

> ***It's unfortunate***, but [there is some problem]
>    ***It's weird***, but [there is something weird going on]

*(**...despite the fact that** [something unspecified] wasn't expected, it has in fact come to pass.)*